# Does baby toothpaste need a hashgacha?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, children-parenting, health-safety-shmira

According to Rav Yisrael Belsky (and based on the reasoning of Rav Yaakov Kaminetsky) toothpaste which contains non-kosher ingredients (such as animal-derived glycerin) is only kosher when the majority ingredients are inedible (which is typically no longer the case today). The Chicago Rabbinical Council (CRC) [mentions](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/status_of_toothpaste.php) that some authorities posit that since one would not eat or serve toothpaste, it does not need to be kosher. Seemingly accordingly, Rav Gedalia Schwartz of the CRC [rules](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/kashrus-corner/175966/crc-kosher-top-ten-questions-for-june-2013.html) that toothpaste does not need to be kosher but should *preferably* not contain glycerin that might have been derived from animals. (The Orthodox Union, on the other hand, seems to consider the presence of glycerin to be more [problematic](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kashruth-issues-of-toothpaste/#fn141190719150cf4c7168cdb).)

At the end of the day, even according to the most lenient view, is there any basis for the practice of giving toothpaste without a reliable *hashgacha* to infants and toddlers (whether [with flouride](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2014/02/11/ada-fluoride-toothpaste-baby-teeth/5389317/) or without) if they are not old enough to reliably spit it out?

Comment: See the article by R. Asher Weiss here https://oukosher.org/content/uploads/2012/12/Mesorah_27.pdf